# SOAP 403 WINDOWS, LOCAL

Tags: php, windows, soap

Добрый день. Коллеги, нужна помощь. Недавно решил попробовать использовать `SOAP`. На локальной машине через программу `SOAPUI` все работает, но через код `php` возвращает ошибку `403 (Access denied)`. Данные указаны правильно. Может, кто сталкивался с таким?

```
      $client = new SoapClient('url');
      $header = new SoapHeader('url', 'Header',array('Username' => 'user', 'Password' => 'password'), false);
      $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
      $data = array('Array' => array('par1' => $par1, 'par2' => $par2));
      try {
        $return = $client->method($data);
      } catch(Exception $e) {
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема, заключалась в том, что я обращался к протоколу https. Исправив на http, все получилось